# Entity Framework: Why is my property empty?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, blazor-server-side

need quick help as the solution is probably easy. Appreciate your help in advance!

I don't understand why `_company.PrimaryAddress.Country` is not being retrieved `OnInitializedAsync()`. But when I run this code, the country is properly saved in the database.

The relevant code are as follows:

```
public class Company
{
    public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(250, ErrorMessage = "Name is too long. (maximum 250 characters)")]
    public string FullLegalName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Registration number is too long. (maximum 100 characters)")]
    public string RegistrationNumber { get; set; }

    public Address PrimaryAddress { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public Guid AddressId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Country is too long. (maximum 100 characters")]
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

And my .razor file are as follows
@page "/basic-information"

```
@using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
@using VisionDemonstrator.Applicant.Web.Data
@using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
@inject IServiceProvider ServiceProvider
@inject NavigationManager NavManager

<h1>Company Details</h1>
<span>This provides the key information about your company for you to open accounts with Standard Chartered Bank</span>

<h2>Basic Information</h2>
<EditForm Model="@_company" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />

    <p>
        <label>
            Company Full Legal Name:
            <InputText id="companyName" @bind-Value="_company.FullLegalName" />
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            Country / Market of Incorporation / Establishment:
            <InputText id="country" @bind-Value="_company.PrimaryAddress.Country" />
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            Company Registration Number:
            <InputText id="registrationNumber" @bind-Value="_company.RegistrationNumber" />
        </label>
    </p>

    <button type="submit">Save and Continue</button>
</EditForm>

@code {
    private Company _company = new Company();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var context = ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<CompanyDbContext>();
        var companies = await context.Companies.ToListAsync();

        if (companies.Count != 0)
        {
            _company = companies[0];
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }

    private async Task HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        var context = ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<CompanyDbContext>();
        if (_company.CompanyId == Guid.Empty)
            await context.AddAsync(_company);

        await context.SaveChangesAsync();

        NavManager.NavigateTo("online-banking");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var companies = await context.Companies
                             .Include(p => p.Address)
                             .ToListAsync();
```